# I am having a problem with Subsetting a data set

Tags: r, subset

I am running these three libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
library(poliscidata)
library(haven)
```

Here is my line of Code:

```
#First, find which variables=Black respondents.
table(data$genfrace)

#3="Black NH (incl. multi-Black)
#Subset
data.2 <- subset(data, data$genfrace=="3")

#Check that subset worked. 
table(data.2$genfrace)
```

This is my error Error:

```
Can't combine ..1 and ..2 . Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.
```

I am using a .Dta File and I am trying to subset the data for Black respondents but this error keeps popping.

Tags

Comment: I can't understand your code.  Can you put the code snippets in code markdown with proper line feeds so we can read it?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I suggest you to clean up your environment and restart the R session. If you still have problems, you need to share an example (providing data!) that actually show the error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `data.2 <- subset(data, data$genfrace=="3")`

please try to use :

`data_2 <- filter(data,genfrace == '3')`